# Cheaper alternative citation managers for Mendeley

Tags: citations, software, tools

I am using Mendeley for paper and citation manager. Mendeley have 2 thing I need:

- index, searchable in all paper (title, author, content, ...)
- auto-lookup all information (title, author, conf, ...). If Mendeley get incorrectly, I can manually input the DOI number, then it correct itself.
- sync (including highlighter and note). Basicly, it work like you note, highlight the pdf and save on Dropbox.

However, my free space is going to fill up. Mendeley paid option is too much for me. I would rather pay for dropbox, but dropbox alone does not index, look up all useful info from my paper.

I am looking for alternative. It does not have to be one software do all thing, but combination of some software is good for me.

For example: I would like a software that index, info-lookup all paper (pdf file) in my local folder. Then I sync the folder with Dropbox (for cheaper storage price).

Comment: Zotero plus webdav comes to mind.

Comment: You may want to check F1000.

Comment: You also have the option to turn off sync in Mendeley for specific folders, so you stop saving attached files to their service. You can then still use the local Organize feature of mendeley to keep the files together, and then just add the folder that Mendeley uses to store your attached files to dropbox/drive/etc. You can also check to make sure you haven't saved very large PDFs you don't actually need (one big scanned book can really eat up file space). These don't answer your question, but are work-arounds that might help anyway.